# How to set profile values for a website visitor programmatically

Tags: xconnect, contact-facets, marketing-control-panel

Using Sitecore 9.1

I need to add profile values programmatically to a profile created under Marketing Control Panel. Once this is achieved, the idea is to use it for personalization by setting up rules. After much of research, I came to know that XConnect Behavior Profiles needs to be used for personalization based on historical profile data and that which would work in multiple visitor sessions, but I need more guidance in achieving it or the code snippet. How can I save the profile data to the visitor/contact and then use it for personalization by setting up rules? Please guide me.

If adding profile score would not be enough / complex, please let me know how I can set pattern cards instead. Thanks

Comment: Why not just edit the profile in Sitecore? Or do you mean assign values to a contact?

Comment: Yes, I want to add those values to the contacts programmatically. Basically I'm looking for a code that saves profile data to contacts (based on some user action) which should be persistent to the contact until cookies are cleared. I'm using Sitecore 9.1.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to run this code in the users session. Like a button click.

```
    private static void ProcessProfile(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item profileItem)
    {
        // update the tracker
        var profile = Tracker.Current.Interaction.Profiles[Constants.Profile.IndustryName];
        var scores = new Dictionary<string, double> { { profileItem.Name, 10 } };

        Log.Debug("KickFire: Looking up profile " + profile.ProfileName, "KickFire");

        profile.Score(scores);
        profile.UpdatePattern();

        Log.Debug("KickFire: ====== ALL IS DONE ======", "KickFire"); 
    }
```

https://github.com/buildabonfire/Bonfire-Company-Personalization/blob/master/src/Feature/KickfireCore/code/Pipelines/createVisit/AdvancedIpData.cs#L132

In the code above the `Constants.Profile.IndustryName` is a string name of the profile. Example is `Focus` from `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles/Focus` profile.

`Sitecore.Data.Items.Item profileItem` is a profile key item under the profile referenced above (Focus). Example is an item with the path `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Profiles/Focus/Background`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Auer..!! Sorry for the delay, will try this code.